# Does OkHttp perform a network read via ResponseBody#string?

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm receiving a `SocketTimeoutException` when accessing the `string()` method on an OkHttp3 `ResponseBody`.

```
var response: Response?
try {
    response = client.newCall(request).execute()
} catch (exception: IOException) { ... }

val result = response.body()?.string()
```

Obviously, a crash occurs because the `SocketTimeoutException` occured outside of my try/catch. I was originally under the impression that `execute()` performed the entire network interaction, but my stack trace tells a different story.

```
Caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
       at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read(Http1Codec.java:363)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:453)
       at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:1135)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.java:199)
       at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:176)
       at com.my.company.Service.sendUpdate(Service.kt:274)
```

Looking at the OkHttp docs & stack trace it does appear that there is a network interaction going on, but I wanted to verify as it goes against my previous understanding.

- Does `string()` perform network operations that could timeout?
- If so, what does `client.newCall(request).execute()` do?

Comment: Put that last code line also in that try block.

Comment: @blackapps yeah, I know how to resolve it - that is why I titled my question as I did

Comment: "Does `string()` perform network operations that could timeout?" -- AFAIK, yes. "what does `client.newCall(request).execute()` do?" -- mostly, it reads in the HTTP headers. After all, the response could be massive. See https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/ for more.